# How to set div height dynamically based on user's browser dimensions

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/FhWxh/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <p>Header</p>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <p><b>Main content</b></p>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        Content
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        Content
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        Content
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        Content
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        Content
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        Content
    </div>

    <div id="sidebar">
        <p><b>Sidebar</b></p>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        Content
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        Content
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        Content
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        Content
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        Content
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <p>Footer</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font: normal 16px/1.5em helvetica, arial, sans-serif
}
p {
    text-align:center;
}
#container {
    width:960px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
#header {
    text-align:center;
    background: #777;
    color:#fff;
    height:50px;
    padding:5px;
}
#content {
    float:right;
    width:610px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#ccc;
    padding:150px 5px;
}
#sidebar {
    float:left;
    width:330px;
    text-align:center;
    height:300px;
    background:#eee;
    padding:15px 5px;
    overflow:auto;
}
#footer {
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
    background: #555;
    color:#fff;
    height:50px;
    padding:5px;
}
```

How do I make the "sidebar" 100% of the height of the user's browser (minus 50 pixels to leave room for the header)?

I believe it's possible to get the user's browser height using javascript and insert it dynamically into the css, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: window.screen.height/window.screen.availHeight -> both work in js

Comment: Actually it is better and possible to do this only with CSS. I would not advice to use JS for such a trivial thing

Comment: 100% on height should do, I agree with caligula...

Comment: height:100% does not work correctly

Comment: Bet, that it is your markup work incorrectly.

Comment: yeah, it should reduce according to the header. http://jsfiddle.net/FhWxh/1/

Comment: Do you want to sidebar stretch to footer or only to the bottom of the browser window?

Comment: had a little fun with the sidebar, hope that doesn't throw you off track ;)

Comment: I want the sidebar to stretch to the footer.  I was thinking of doing a jQuery script that would allow the div to follow the user as they scroll down the main content.  But the fixed position might work well too.

Comment: Shouvik - do you have any tips on how I can make the div look better when the user scrolls down?  Right now, as the user scrolls, it leaves an empty area at the top where the header was.  Also, at the bottom, the div goes over the footer

Comment: You have a special background on your sidebar? I suppose that you only need a background to stretch to the bottom, right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$('#sidebar').height($(window).height() - 50)
```

Comment: @Gregg You must include jQuery in your page.

Answer (score 2):

Div will resize based on browser size

```
$(window).on('load resize', function(){
    $('#div').height($(this).height());
    $('#div').width($(this).width());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying not to use js, is this the sort of effect you wanted? http://jsfiddle.net/FhWxh/4/

a bit more complete http://jsfiddle.net/FhWxh/13/show/
the whole content size is set by the wrapper (set to 960px) and the footer and header are fixed into position within this, and the content and sidebar are in the container class you used earlier. Its not perfect but i hope it helps

Comment: Oh wow, that's fantastic.  This is exactly what I wanted.  Didn't realize I could do it without JS.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Oops, one thing though:  When you increase the width of the browser, the container div stretches out more than 960px and leaves a big white space.  Do you know why that is?

Comment: I forgot to wrap it all up, have a look at the update :). You can do a lot before hitting the JS

Comment: Be aware that this solution practically renders your site useless on any mobile browser.

Comment: Yeah its quite badly bashed together. If you want a good layout solution, I would recommend http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/. It has lots of helpers for things like sidebars and headers/footer and alot more, much of it free of JS